# Kafka2.2.0 with SASL-SCRAM - SSL peer is not authenticated, returning ANONYMOUS instead

Tags: apache-kafka, sasl-scram

Kafka **SSL peer is not authenticated, returning ANONYMOUS instead** error when client connecting the brokers SASL port, it allows the connection on PLAINTEXT or SSL ports.

I have kafka 2.2.0 in windows systems with SSL enabled, where the kafka broker plaintext is running on 9092 and SSL on 9093. **On top of that, configured the SASL with SCRAM mechanism with listener port as 9094**, ending-up with error as mentioned in problem summary while running producer as **kafka-console-producer.bat --broker-list localhost:9094 --topic xxx**

Here are the SASL configurations, **not provided other configuration like basic and SSL**

**zookeeper.properties**

```
authProvider.1=org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.SASLAuthenticationProvider
requireClientAuthScheme=sasl
jaasLoginRenew=3600000
```

**server.properties**

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092,SSL://0.0.0.0:9093,SASL_SSL://0.0.0.0:9094
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,SSL://localhost:9093,SASL_SSL://localhost:9094
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=SCRAM-SHA-256
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=SCRAM-SHA-256
```

**zookeeper_server_jaas.conf**

```
Server {
   org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required
   username="admin"
   password="admin-pwd"
   user_admin="admin-pwd"
   user_other1="other1-pwd"
   user_other2="other2-pwd";
};
```

**producer.properties**

```
security.protocol=SSL
```

**kafka_server_jaas.conf**

```
KafkaServer {
   org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required
   username="admin"
   password="admin-pwd";
};
Client {
   org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
   username="admin"
   password="admin-pwd";
};
```

**kafka_client_jaas.conf**

```
KafkaClient {
    org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required
    username="admin"
    password="admin-pwd";
};
```

**Start the Zookeeper as**

```
SET ZOO_LOG_DIR=C:/Work/kafka_2.11-2.2.0-for-ssl/zookeeper-data
SET KAFKA_HOME=C:/Work/kafka_2.11-2.2.0-for-ssl
set KAFKA_OPTS=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=%KAFKA_HOME%/config/zookeeper_server_jaas.conf
zookeeper-server-start.bat %KAFKA_HOME%/config/zookeeper.properties
```

**Start the kafka as**

```
set KAFKA_HOME=C:/Work/kafka_2.11-2.2.0-for-ssl
set KAFKA_OPTS=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=%KAFKA_HOME%/config/kafka_server_jaas.conf
kafka-server-start.bat %KAFKA_HOME%/config/server.properties
```

**Start the Producer as**

```
SET KAFKA_HOME=C:/Work/kafka_2.11-2.2.0-for-ssl
set KAFKA_OPTS=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=%KAFKA_HOME%/config/kafka_client_jaas.conf
kafka-console-producer.bat --broker-list localhost:9094 --topic xxx
```

The producer is only working if I use the broker port as 9092. Did I missed something and end-up with mis-configuration. Any inputs?

**Updated:**

Here is the error while connecting the producer/consumer

[2019-10-14 15:39:42,108] DEBUG [SslTransportLayer channelId=127.0.0.1:9094-127.0.0.1:63848-0 key=sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@222a223c] SSL peer is not authenticated, returning ANONYMOUS instead (org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer)
[2019-10-14 15:39:42,108] DEBUG [SslTransportLayer channelId=127.0.0.1:9094-127.0.0.1:63848-0 key=sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@222a223c] SSL handshake completed successfully with peerHost '127.0.0.1' peerPort 63848 peerPrincipal 'User:ANONYMOUS' cipherSuite 'TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256' (org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer)
[2019-10-14 15:39:42,108] DEBUG Set SASL server state to HANDSHAKE_OR_VERSIONS_REQUEST during authentication (org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslServerAuthenticator)
[2019-10-14 15:39:42,108] DEBUG Handling Kafka request API_VERSIONS during authentication (org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslServerAuthenticator)
[2019-10-14 15:39:42,108] DEBUG Set SASL server state to HANDSHAKE_REQUEST during authentication (org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslServerAuthenticator)
[2019-10-14 15:39:42,108] DEBUG Set SASL server state to FAILED during authentication (org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslServerAuthenticator)
[2019-10-14 15:39:42,108] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=0] Failed authentication with 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1 (Unexpected Kafka request of type METADATA during SASL handshake.) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. Authentication with SASL SCRAM wasn't working on 2.2.x and 2.3.x Kafka versions. On 2.1 it was OK.

In the end I resolved the issue by providing zookeeper chroot path (**/kafkaTest**) when creating principals:

```
./kafka-configs --zookeeper zookeeper-01:2181/kafkaTest --alter --add-config 'SCRAM-SHA-256=[password=admin-secret],SCRAM-SHA-512=[password=admin-secret]' --entity-type users --entity-name admin
```

Seems like when credentials are created in zookeeper root path, Kafka can't find them to validate.

I hope it will solve your issue as well!

Comment: Did you do any zookeeper configuration for 'kafkaTest' before? When add uses as mentioned, I am getting message as "Path length must be > 0"

Comment: This worked... For me, it was :2181/kafka. Thank you very much!!